# Font family set on Materia UI theme not working on browsers other than Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, material-ui, material-design

Need to override some elements with a specific font, which works fine on Chrome, but not any other browsers (Safari, FireFox, etc). Is there anything that was missed?

Here is my code:

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
        MuiTypography: {
            h1: {
                fontFamily: 'Source Sans Pro'
            }
        }
    }
});

const MyApp = () => {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <CssBaseline />

            <Typography variant='h1'>Source Sans Pro font applied on Chrome, but not on other browsers</Typography>
        </ThemeProvider?
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it would seem this and other fonts I was using work out-of-the-box with Chrome but not other browsers.

So basically, had to do the whole dance to add them on my project, in my case through [webpack](https://chriscourses.com/blog/loading-fonts-webpack). Basically:

- Install font-awesome in the project

```sh
npm install -S font-awesome
```

- Create a style.scss file in the project's root
- Import font-awesome in the newly created `style.scss` file:

```
@import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
```

- Fint my fonts on https://fonts.google.com/
- Select the styles, generate the link to import them and do so from the newly created `style.scss`

```
@import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;1,300;1,400;1,600&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Serif+Pro:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;1,300;1,400;1,600&display=swap');
```

- Import the `style.scss` file from my project entry point (in my case `index.js`, but could also be `app.js`.

```js
import './style.scss'; // here
import React from 'react';
...

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        .... My App...
    </div>
    , document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

- Finally would also need to rebuild since I am using webpack